# Prevent Program (.exe) from starting DIRECTLY (Only allow execution from shortcut)?

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64

Is there a way to prevent direct startup of a .exe program, and only start up when a shortcut is run? I'd like this to work also when opening up a filetype that is assigned to a program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes close to what you want is checking for certain command line parameters. This is actually a rather common way for concealed executions - for instance programs that want you to run a loader program first (online games would be an example).
So you would have to generate a shortcut that privdes the specific command line arguments needed for the start. This ensures that your exe cannot be executed directly, however there are no guaranties that a specific shortcut file is startet as it only provides a link to the exe file.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you to everyone else who answered!

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible, in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the shortcut is executing the program in its location. The .exe has to be executable for the shortcut to work. Assigned file extensions also execute the actual .exe the shortcut is just a symbolic link to the actual file.

If you can give more information as to what your trying to accomplish I could maybe offer another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way built in to do this, as an executable is still launched as that user by the shortcut. You can disable shortcut locations, allow only certain executables, etc but not deny access to executable but also allow it via shortcut.